# DLL Load Failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: python, c, extension-modules

So I have a situation where I need to make binary patches and then be able to apply them from within python. I found [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) which looks like a great algorithm and has a [python extension module](http://starship.python.net/crew/atuining/cx_bsdiff/index.html), but that extension module doesn't have a windows installer past Python 2.5

Alright, so having never even written C seriously, let alone attempted a python extension module, I set out to compile it myself. After a few hours of bashing my head against a DLL load error with MinGW32, I managed to get it compiled and built using the setup.py provided in the source of the project. However, upon importing the resulting bsdiff module, I get:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

I'm running 64 bit python.

Any advice?

Comment: Try taking a look at the DLL. Does it look like a DLL? (e.g. does it start with `MZ`?)

Comment: Did you have the same version of Visual Studio as the one used to compile Python? Are you trying to use a 32-bit extension module with 64-bit Python (or vice versa)?

Comment: `%1` looks like a string token gone wrong to me.

Comment: @nneonneo I compiled it with MinGW32, as I stated in the question

Comment: @Aesthete: It's not an uncommon Windows error: https://www.google.com/search?q=1+is+not+a+valid+win32+application

Comment: @glittershark: So is your Python 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: @nneonneo I'm running 64 bit python. Is it possible that it would compile a 32-bit DLL? How would I force it to do otherwise?

Comment: _Normally_ compiling Python modules should give you the same configuration. But, if you have another version of Python installed, you might run into problems -- maybe MinGW supplies one, or you've got some installed Python elsewhere that is interfering.

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bsdiff4

Comment: @cgohlke that worked! Thank you so much. Post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's a mismatch in versions of Python and pywin32. I got the same error message after installing pywin32 in a virtual environment using easy_install:

`(py351env) C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\Downloads>easy_install pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.5.exe`

When I tried to import win32gui I got exactly the same error:

`DLL Load Failed: %1 is not a valid win32 application`

Googling for the error message led me to this post where cgohlke suggested to download the pywin32 package from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

I downloaded the 64bit version and installed it via pip:

`pip install pywin32-220-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`

Right away I got an error message that my python version does not match with the package I was trying to install. So I typed 'python' in my command line to launch the interpreter, and indeed the python installed in my 64bit machine was a 32bit python. After uninstalling python and correctly installing the 64bit one, this error disappeared, whether I use easy_install to install pywin32 from the sourceforge project, or I use pip to install the wheel file from gohlke.