# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

I have a 64 bit architecture system.  I installed Python 2.7.5.  I then started the installation of pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7.  That failed with the "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" error message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a compatibility issue between 32 bit and 64 bit. So, either try 64 bit Python or 32 bit Python with 32 bit pywin32 installer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a port issue with the binary see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434283/dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application), it is similar.